# How to force firefox to remember passwords?

Tags: 12.04, firefox, password

In firefox, some passwords I have cannot be saved (I'm not even asked for that), for example fab.com or battle.net

How can I make Firefox remember those passwords?

Comment: Make sure you are not in Private Browsing mode. Also, check `Edit -> Preferences -> History`, make sure Firefox is NOT set to `Firefox will: Never remember history`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. There is a firefox addon, called:

[Saved Password editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/saved-password-editor/?src=api)
After filling in password and username, you can simply rightclick in the filed and choose "save login data" like shown here:

[image: Saved Password Editor - Example]

It works for most of the websites who have problems with saving passwords.

An alternative is:
[RememberPass](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/rememberpass/)

Answer (score 3):

Some sites will not let you remember their passwords.

> Some websites use JavaScript to clear fields or use autocomplete=off
>   to prevent the browser from storing the name and password and Firefox
>   won't save the name in such cases.<sup>1</sup>

To see how you can workaround that, see [Firefox Support](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/928225), and [Here](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/764457).

Also [How to geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/?post_type=post&p=62980) has a step by step action.

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Firefox Support](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/928225)</sup>

Comment: And don't forget that there needs to be a mechanism to 'not remember', to protect SSN or CreditCard number fields.

Comment: @david6 Excellent point :)

Comment: @ph1b: if it works, please consider accepting the answer (check mark on left) to close out the question as "answered".

Comment: A workaround would be nice. Otherwise, this appears to be a "link-only" answer. Please consider posting a workaround if you know of one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works for the JavaScript clearing sites mentionned, but it works for me in Firefox: Edit-Preferences-Security-Click to remember passwords for sites and make sure the websites you want to save passwords for aren't on the Exceptions list and if they are remove them (this might be why you don't get asked to save them in the first place, they might have been placed on the Exceptions list at some point).